# Display image from imagettftext

Tags: php, html

I have code to generate an image:

```php
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $members = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://discord.com/api/guilds/828207694284193802/widget.json'), true)['members'];

    $membersCount = 0;
    foreach ($members as $member) {
        if ($member['status'] == 'online') {
            $membersCount++;
        }
    }

    $img = imagecreatetruecolor(380, 80);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255,255,255);

    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    $font = "arial.ttf";

    $txt = "ONLINE: " . $membersCount;

    $image_width = imagesx($img);
    $image_height = imagesy($img);

    $text_box = imagettfbbox(30,0, $font,$txt);

    $text_width = $text_box[2]-$text_box[0];
    $text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1];

    $x = ($image_width/2) - ($text_width/2);
    $y = ($image_height/2) - ($text_height/2);

    imagettftext($img, 30, 0, $x, $y, $white, $font, $txt);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

And I want to display a result on my forum:

```html
<img src="http://s52518.web101.svpj.pl/banners/counter_dc.php" alt="" />
```

But the result is:

[image]

Or an empty box:

[image]

My PHP code is working well:

[image]

I want add the image in HTML to my sidebar/box (I don't know how it's named). It's a [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord) online users counter.

Comment: But why to complicate as an image to show a simple text ONLINE : 2 ?

Comment: Because it will be image with background instead of black color bg.

Comment: Where are you trying to embed the image? Is it a HTTPS site? The browser would refuse to load insecure content (HTTP). Your link http://s52518.web101.svpj.pl/banners/counter_dc.php is not working ... it is also possible that additional messages / errors are printed, which would invalidate the PNG and lead to a broken image.

Comment: @Alex That's an old question as you can see. I marked them as "undeleted" because I am trying to unblock my account and get positive votes.

Yes, it was then a server problem that was refusing access to the image for some reason.

Comment: There is no question in this post. Debug questions require a [mre]. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [ask] [Help]